# Number of labelled graphs with $n$ nodes, $k$ edges and $t$ triangles

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

How many *labelled* undirected graphs are there with precisely $n$ vertices, $k$ edges, and $t$ triangle subgraphs?  (By triangle I mean a graph with three vertices and three edges.)

(Clarification: I am interested only in graphs with no self loops or multiple edges.  The graphs do not need to be connected.)

I would appreciate any pointers to results on this problem (exact or approximate). The results I am able to find are typically for unlabelled graphs ([e.g. a count up to $n=12$](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/cospectral/triangles.html)), but in this case I am interested in *labelled* ones.

I am also interested in possible computational methods for this that are better than brute enumeration.

Comment: I haven't the faintest myself, but in the hope that this leads you somewhere: Cayley's formula for the numbers of labeled trees on $n$ vertices in $n^{n-2}$.

Comment: The number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges should be: $n(n-1)/2 \choose k$

Comment: @M.M That's the easy part.  Now constrain the triangle count :-)